# Auto updater for jetty server web app and lib files

Tags: java, jetty, auto-update

**Jetty server** is running as service in our client retail stores for a POS application. Right now I'm manually take a folder release and installing there by Team viewer and I need to connect and update war/jar files for any changes.

For this I need a **auto updater** that can get changes from a common web server and do clean auto update. Changes would be either War file or lib files.

Can any one suggest best how to do it this best way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an out of the box solution, but this was one of the design considerations for the deployment manager work we did on jetty a couple of years ago.  This would ultimately be a custom Provider implementation that instead of a local file scanner looking for changes, could look for changes somewhere else, grab those resources and then trigger the associated behavior in jetty.

We obviously haven't gotten around to implementing this sort of behavior yet but it is something that would be fun to have in jetty if you want to write something and contribute it back to the project or sponsor the development of it.

If you don't want to have a solution that is contained within jetty itself you can cobble together something that might work using a combination of shell scripts and cron that would wake up periodically and check a url for new content, download it and then use the hot deployment mechanism to trigger a reload of the relevant files, but that is more of a one off and likely isn't generally useful, but I can see how it would work in some situations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking to write my own, I will work for it.

Comment: Then look to the existing WebAppProvider and good luck! - any question s on that ping me on irc 'jmcconnell' on irc.freenode.org